# How to callapse div using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

How to callapse div using JAVASCRIPT.

**No** **AJAX**, **No** **JQuery**, only pure javascript.

My try not working.

Example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="test();">click!</button>

<div id = "page">
a
<br>
b
<br>
c
<br>
d
<br>
e
<br>
f
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
    var height = document.getElementById('page').offsetHeight;
    myLoop(height);
}


function myLoop (height) {           
   setTimeout(function () {                      
      if (height > 0) {      
        console.log(height);
        height--;     
        document.getElementById('page').style.width=height+'px';
        myLoop(height);             
      }                        
   }, 1)
}
</script>
```

Can you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it `[...].style.height` instead of `[...].style.width`. And I think that you wanted to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with CSS transitions, quite easily. No `setTimeout()` needed. All you need JavaScript for it to trigger the addition of a CSS class that adjusts the `height` of the element directly. The **[CSS `transition` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)** will perform the actual animation of the `height` for you.

This is a better solution than `setTimeout()`, because (depending on the processing power of the client), `setTimeout()` can cause a jittery animation and CSS is less expensive, in terms of performance.

```js
var target = null;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Get reference to target and store in higher scoped variable
  // so that we don't have to scan for it again later.
  target = document.getElementById('page');
  
  var h = window.getComputedStyle(target).height; // Get its computed height
  target.style.height = h;                        // Set that height explicitly
});


// ****************************************************************
// Get reference to button "trigger" and set up 
// a click event handler for it. Do this in JavaScript,
// not via HTML event attributes such as "onclick".
var btn = document.getElementById("btnHide");
btn.addEventListener("click", hide);

function hide() {
  // Simply apply a class that resets the height.
  // Since the element is pre-configured for a transition
  // the change in height will be animated.
  target.classList.add("hidden");
}


// ****************************************************************
var btn = document.getElementById("btnShow");
btn.addEventListener("click", show);

function show() {
  // Just remove the class that cause the element to become hidden
  target.classList.remove("hidden");
}

// ****************************************************************
// This code makes the show/hide happen with just one button "trigger"

var btn = document.getElementById("btnToggle");
btn.addEventListener("click", toggle);

function toggle() {
  // Just remove the class that cause the element to become hidden
  target.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
/* Default style for element to be animated */
.target {
  /* This sets up a transition on all properties that may change in the future
     to animate to their new value over the course of 2 seconds. */
  transition:all 2s; 
  
  /* This is needed for the contents to actually disappear. Without it,
     as the div shrinks, the content will just overflow the boundaries
     of the div and continue to show. */
  overflow:hidden;   
}

/* This gets applied upon the click of the trigger button. 
   !important is required to override inline style applied
   via code.
*/
.hidden { height:0 !important; }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnHide">Hide</button>
<button type="button" id="btnShow">Show</button>
<button type="button" id="btnToggle">Toggle Show/Hide</button>

<div id = "page" class="target">
a
<br>
b
<br>
c
<br>
d
<br>
e
<br>
f
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any way, how to do this without static set for `height: 100px`. I need some dynamic solution.

Comment: @praeslai An explicit `height` must be set, but I have altered the answer so that is done dynamically.

Comment: Thank you very much, if you have a few free minutes, you can add "decollapse" options.

Comment: @praeslai That's just a matter of adding another "trigger" button and in that button's click event handler, removing the `hidden` class. I will update the answer to show this. I've also added code to show how a single button can be used to toggle the show/hide state regardless of what it currently is.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is `style.height` instead of `style.width` and everything perfect fine.

There is no other issue but it is a matter of visual representation

To verify it, add a border to *div#page* as seen in the snippet

```js
function test() {
  var height = document.getElementById('page').offsetHeight;
  myLoop(height);
}


function myLoop(height) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (height > 0) {
      height--;
      document.getElementById('page').style.height = height + 'px';
      myLoop(height);
    }
  }, 10)
}
```

```css
#page {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="test();">click!</button>

<div id="page">
  a
  <br> b
  <br> c
  <br> d
  <br> e
  <br> f
</div>
```

## Where is the problem

It is the overflow.

set `overflow:hidden` to achieve what you want

```js
function test() {
  var height = document.getElementById('page').offsetHeight;
  myLoop(height);
}


function myLoop(height) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (height > 0) {
      height--;
      document.getElementById('page').style.height = height + 'px';
      myLoop(height);
    }
  }, 10)
}
```

```css
#page {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="test();">click!</button>

<div id="page">
  a
  <br> b
  <br> c
  <br> d
  <br> e
  <br> f
</div>
```